# What is most simple way to send notification of unexpected events to users of Android application?

Tags: android, mobile, notifications

For example I expect this kind of situation: data in my application lost relevance and so it usless until update. And until update it have to show users some predefined message.

Is here any simple and free solution to this task?

Guess I can use some server to somehow send simple messages... but it sounds way too complicated.

If this is important I use Xamarin.

Update: main difficulty here is fact - my application can't in any way define if it's outdated or not. This may happen in random moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the requirement is not very clear I assume Update here means app update.

each time user launches app make call to an api on ur server to check if user needs to update app

If that returns true take user to a static view that says app needs update and redirects user to google play to install updates

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using a server, you should try Firebase (https://firebase.google.com/). More specifically, you should use Firebase Remote Config (https://firebase.google.com/features/remote-config/).

Define in a key-value pair of something like minimum_app_version_required in Firebase Remote Config. Every time user opens the your app, compare the values of app version and minimum_app_version_required that you are getting from Firebase console and show a dialog box accordingly. You can also change the value of minimum_app_version_required anytime you want.

Comment: Very interesting. Is it completely free?

Comment: @InfernumDeus Yes!

Comment: sweet! Thank you. I will look it later.

Answer (score 0):

Just set some internal flag. That when that situation occurs, you can set the flag to true and just edit whatever layout element you are using such as listView or any other element with your predefined messages saved in strings.xml. You can also build any custom pop up screen, depends how you want to show them. Let me know if you didn't understand or exactly how you want?

Answer (score 0):

Need to implement versioning for this problem. To achieve this, you have to maintain a version number in server, this is the version number you app will have to save and  use it to validate with server. If both are not same, then app will get the latest data from the server.